# Show and Hide in forms using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form with some fields. I hide one of them using Jquery, when I select something in selected index. After the form was filled I am try to submit that. At the submission it have the hided field too. How can I avoid the hided field and its data on the submission of the form.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Remove the elements instead of just hiding them! Problem solved, next.

Comment: I tried that too but for different things I have to add it again but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You could just check the css display property of the element first and only post it if its not 'none'

```
if ($(#element).css( "display" ) != 'none') {
     // post it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `select` with an option that triggers the removal of the form. You can then set the `input` you would like to hide to `disabled` and hide it. The disabled input will not be submitted with the rest of your information. Then you could remove `disabled` and show it if the user selects another option.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input class="hide-me" type="text" value="hello"/>
    <select>
        <option>Choose</option>
        <option value="choose me">Choose Me</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$("select").change(function(){
   if($(this).val() == "choose me"){
      $(".hide-me").attr("disabled", true).hide();
   }else{
      $(".hide-me").attr("disabled", false).show();    
   }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/p23cf1L4/1/)

Comment: For the sake of the SO community, please don't feed [help vampires](http://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm).

Comment: @showdev I know, I know. But besides the missing code the question seemed pretty straight forward

Answer (score -1):

Make the item disabled. e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="lname" disabled>
```

Comment: I will not suits for my thing, I have dozzens of fields in my form. I have to hide one field when we select an item in another field and also it should be show if we reselect the previous one.

Comment: @TGayu You can apply this concept to your code (which we haven't seen). SO is not a coding service.

Comment: @showdev yes I have but I am new to this. I donot know where to put my code and also I have a bunch of code it may be more than 100 lines